# Android have a style add properties instead of replacing properties

Tags: android, xml, styles

Probably not a very clear question, but here's the deal:

I have a style called Button, this style contains a few properties.

There's one property that's only available to API-21 >

So I created a Button style in the styles-v21, which looks like:

`<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
 </style>`

All the other properties are lost. Is there a way to merge styles' Button with styles-v21's Button?

Comment: Have the style inherit from the base style that you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to extend parent style:

```
<style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:stateListAnimator">@null</item>
</style>
```

You can replace "Widget.AppCompat.Button" with any other button style.